# Replacing A Trane thermostat with A Honeywell Wifi thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, wifi, rewire

[image][image][image][image]Heres what I have.
On A Trane brand thermostat

Red wire = R
Black wire = W2
White wire = W1
yellow wire = Y
Green wire = G
Orange wire = O
Blue wire = B or from what i'm told is my C wire??

And i'm trying to hookup new honeywell wifi thermostat. Which has these options.Can anyone help A brother out? Can get the heat to work but the cool mode  just blows heat also???

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the air-handler/furnace?

Comment: took some shots not sure if you can make any sense of it

Comment: Did you reprogram the system setting from type 1 to type 7?